# How do I make LLVM opt output an IR file when given an IR file?

Tags: c++, compilation, llvm, llvm-clang

I use LLVM `opt` to run a pass using, e.g, `opt -load libMyPass.so my-pass foo.ll > foo1.ll`.

`foo.ll` is an IR file, and I want `foo1.ll` to contain the result, of running the pass, in IR format. But `foo1.ll` becomes a bitcode file, so I need to issue `llvm-dis foo1.ll` to transform it into IR format.

How do I avoid having to run `llvm-dis`, and make `opt` transform from IR format to IR format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`opt` has a nice option for doing that:

```
-S           - Write output as LLVM assembly
```

I guess what confuses you is that LLVM assembly is a synonym for LLVM IR.